# how to convert python functions to classes that do the same thing

Tags: python, class

I am trying to create python classes from a program that I wrote in functions only. So the code is working fine with functions but giving an error/errors when I convert the code to python classes.

Functions:

```py
def eachList(index):
    Series=df_ideal.iteritems()
    bigList = []
    for (columnName,item) in Series:
        bigList.append(item)
    return bigList[index]
```

```
def isResult(listing):
    mylist=[]
    for i in range(len([column_name for column_name in df_ideal])):
        result = map(lambda x:x*x,residual(listing,eachList(i)))
        Sum = int(sum(result))
        mylist.append(Sum)
    return(mylist)
```

With Classes

```
class Task1:
    
    def __init__(self,train,ideal):
        self.train = train
        self.ideal = ideal
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.ideal[index]
    
    def residual(self,lst1,lst2):
        self.subtracted = []
        for item1,item2 in zip(lst1,lst2):
            self.subtracted.append(item1-item2)
        return self.subtracted
    
    def eachList(self,index):
        Series=df_ideal.iteritems()
        self.bigList = []
        for (columnName,item) in Series:
            self.bigList.append(item)
        return self.bigList[index]
```

Inheritance

```
class Resultant(Task1):
    def __init__(self,train,ideal):
        super().__init__(train,ideal)
      
    def isResult(self,listing):
        mylist=[]
        for i in range(len([column_name for column_name in df_ideal])): 
            result = map(lambda x:x*x,Task1.residual(listing,Task1.eachList(i)))
            Sum = int(sum(result))
            mylist.append(Sum)
        return(mylist)
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Don't do this.  Changing your local variables to instance attributes just creates possibilities for your function invocations to interfere with each other.  Putting something in a class just for the sake of using classes does *not* make your code better.

Comment: Even without that, the structure of this code is really unnecessarily complex -- your `eachList` builds the entire list just so it can return a single element from it, and you call that over and over in a loop.  Why not just return the list (once) and then iterate over it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're hitting (I'm guessing) is that you're calling `Task1.residual` as if it's a class method, when it's not:

```
result = map(lambda x:x*x,Task1.residual(listing,Task1.eachList(i)))
```

For this to work you should be calling `self.residual`.

However, I think it would be better to just have a simple set of functions, since there's nothing in the implementation of these functions that requires any kind of persistent state to be shared between them.  The logic is simple enough that each could be written as a single list comprehension:

```
def eachList():
    return [item for _columnName, item in df_ideal.iteritems()]

def residual(lst1, lst2):
    return [item1 - item2 for item1, item2 in zip(lst1, lst2)]

def isResult(listing):
    return [sum(x * x for x in residual(listing, item)) for item in eachList()]
```

Comment: Thank you Samwise. Your guess is correct.It worked very well. Thanks once more , you are a star